# Simplify a rate limiting algorithm for Node.js server

Tags: node.js, algorithm, server, rate-limiting

I came up with a naive solution for a rate limiting algorithm for a Node.js server and I believe there is a way to simplify it, but I am not sure how yet.

We want to limit requests to 50 per second. So if the newest request comes in and the time between the newest request and request that is 50 places back is less than one second, we should reject the new request.

The naive way to implement this would be to have a simple array that contains 50 timestamps. Every-time an event comes in we assign it a value of Date.now() / process.hrtime(). We then look at the timestamp value of the 50th (last) timestamp in the queue and the new request's Date.now() value, and if the difference in timestamps is greater than 1 second, then we accept the new request and unshift it onto the "queue", and pop the oldest timestamp off the queue. However, if the difference is less than 1 second, we must reject the request, and we don't unshift it onto the queue, and we don't pop the oldest timestamp off.

Here is the code I have on an Express server

```
var mostRecentRequestsTimestamps = [];

app.use(function(req,res,next){

    if(req.baymaxSource && String(req.baymaxSource).toUpperCase() === 'XRE'){

        var now = process.hrtime(); //nanoseconds

        if(mostRecentRequestsTimestamps.length < 50){
            mostRecentRequestsTimestamps.unshift(now);
            next();
        }
        else{
            var lastItem = mostRecentRequestsTimestamps.length -1;
            if(now - mostRecentRequestsTimestamps[lastItem] < 1000){  // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
                res.status(503).json({error: 'Server overwhelmed by XRE events'});
            }
            else{
                mostRecentRequestsTimestamps.pop();
                mostRecentRequestsTimestamps.unshift(now);
                next();
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        next();
    }

});
```

As you could see, it only blocks events if they are coming from one particular source, so it shouldn't starve other types of requests. This logic requires a data structure of 50 timestamps, which is basically nothing, but I would like a way to simplify this even further if possible. Anyone have any ideas? thanks

Comment: Doesn't your solution require an array for every separate user that is using your service?  There are many, many articles written about various strategies for rate limiting including many with sample code.  Have you done any of your own research on this yet?  If so, what did you find and what questions do you have about what has already been written on this topic?  If not, then I'd suggest you start with reading about what has already been developed in this area.

Comment: no, this is just a "singlethreaded" node.js server, just need one array..I see a lot of rate limiting libraries and examples out there that just seem like they are either blanket solutions or poorly implemented, etc.

Comment: If you have only one array and you have N different users making requests of your server, then you will be rate limiting the entire population together.  UserA might make 50 rapid requests and userB might make one request and, if userB gets a bit unlucky with his timing relative to userA, then userB gets rate limited even though he only made one single request.  This is NOT how rate limiting should work.  I think you need to rethink what you're doing.  The fact that node.js is single threaded has nothing to do with this issue.  Many different users can still make requests.

Comment: Some existing implementations and algorithms: [node.js rate limiter](https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter), [ratelimit.js](http://ratelimit.io/), [Token Bucket Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket), [Leaky Bucket Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket).

Comment: thanks I will check them out

Comment: One major question is about your objective.   Are you trying to keep one single user for over-using the server so that a given user will be limited in how many requests they can do within a prescribed time period?  Or are you trying to restrict the total number of requests that can be made within some given time frame and any user who comes along may get penalized if the server happens to be busy.  One is about keeping a single user from misbehaving and messing up the service for everyone else.  The other is about protecting the server, but does not attempt any notion of fairness.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are absolutely right about the rate limit by user, that makes a lot of sense and I hadn't thought about that - but that's why I say we don't want a blanket solution, because our server is only getting requests from one other server

Comment: All the solutions out there allow you to treat all requests as if they are coming from the same origin if that's how you want to do it.  The more I think about it, the more I'm thinking that your question isn't really appropriate here on Stack Overflow.  You're essentially asking people for design advice which has no specific correct answer rather than asking a specific question with a specific answer.

Comment: I am not going to pick a fight with you since you are always so helpful on SO :) but I suppose you are more than welcome to (a) improve my solution (b) point me to existing solutions which you already have, or (c) provide an alternative solution and elaborate on it briefly in an answer or (d) ?

Comment: I want my team to implement this ourselves, we want full knowledge and full responsbility of how it works. I don't want to use someone else's library for this.

Comment: If you showed your code, described what was working well with it and what you were unhappy with and asked a specific question about how to improve some aspect of it, that would certainly fit the guidelines here.  For example, I don't even know what's wrong with having a single array of 50 timestamps.  Seems darn simple to me.  So, I don't really even understand what question you're asking.

Comment: I added the code, I agree that without code it is bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simplest I can make it:

```
// oldest request time is at front of the array
var recentRequestTimes = [];
var maxRequests = 50;
var maxRequestsTime = 1000;

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    if(req.baymaxSource && String(req.baymaxSource).toUpperCase() === 'XRE'){
        var old, now = Date.now();
        recentRequestTimes.push(now);
        if (recentRequestTimes.length >= maxRequests) {
            // get the oldest request time and examine it
            old = recentRequestTimes.shift();
            if (now - old <= maxRequestsTime) {
                // old request was not very long ago, too many coming in during that maxRequestsTime
                res.status(503).json({error: 'Exceeded 50 requests per second for XRE events'});
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    next();
});
```

This is conceptually different than your implementation in two ways:

1. I use the `recentRequestTimes` array in increasing order (just made a lot more logical sense to my programming brain)
2. I always add every request to the array, even when it's overloaded.  You were not counting requests that hit overload which I think is wrong.  This also simplifies the code since you can just add the current time at the start of the function in one place and then just process the array.

Comment: Thanks this looks good, I tested it and it works. I believe it is a simple improvement over strange rate limiting implementations such as this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/rolling-rate-limiter

Comment: I created my own library that implements this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/curtain, it is a work in progress but the plan is for it to be simpler than any other libs